# Finding Conditional Expectation and variance E(Y|X=x)

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I want to find the conditional Expectation and variance of random function Y for a given value of random function X, i.e. E(Y|X=x).

Here X is x(t) and Y is x(t+τ). Also, x(t) is a stationary Gaussian process with mean=0 and variance = 1. Here's what I did:-

So, I found the joint probability function of X and Y, i.e., P(X,Y). Divided it by Marginal density function of X, i.e., P(X) and got the P(Y|X). I have the value of ρ, and variance for X & Y = 1 and E(X)=E(Y)=0.

I know x(t) = 0.5 and τ=0.1 now. How do I find E(Y|X=0.5) and Var(Y|X=0.5)?

Any hint or solution? I know to find the conditional expectation I need to multiply the PDF with y and integrate over y. But I really need an example.

Comment: To anyone who comes across a similar problem, read the link below. Its informative. The expression for conditional mean and variance is derived. http://www.ltcc.ac.uk/courses/Measure-Theoretic%20Probability/LTCCsoln2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Hi if your process is Gaussian then the joint law  $(X_t,X_{t+\tau})$ is a multivariate Gaussian random variable. You only need to apply in this case the formulas in wiki link at the section on [conditional distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) to get what you want.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you. Can you shed some light on this too?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034832/marginal-probability-of-stochastic-process

Answer (score 0):

great to see you are interested in GPs. Someone asked a similar question about how to make predictions on a GP and I think I gave a fairly comprehensive work through with sample data that they gave.

I think seeing it in action will answer your question. [Here is the link.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069344/gaussian-process-regression/1072473#1072473)