# Marginal Probability of Stochastic Process

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I have a wide sense stationary stochastic process x(t)=asin(2πf0t)+bcos(2πf0t) where a & b are independent gaussian random variables. How can I find the Marginal probability of x(t)?

I am confused even about the very meaning of it. How can I find marginal probability of x(t) if I don't have any other function to find its joint probability distribution with? Does it automatically imply that the other function is x(t+τ) ?

Should I just substitute x(t) as 'x' in the usual marginal gaussian probability distribution equation shown below?

[image]

The mean and variance for a,b were given as zero and 1 respectively so I calculated the autocorrelation function for x(t). Does that have any use in such scenario?

Comment: Hi how x(t) is a stochastic process when it is constant for all t ? Best regards

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are independent gaussian random variables **and if $a$ and $b$ are centered with the same variance $\sigma^2$** then, for every $t$, $x(t)=a\sin(2πf_0t)+b\cos(2πf_0t)$ is gaussian centered with variance $\sigma^2\sin^2(2πf_0t)+\sigma^2\cos^2(2πf_0t)=\sigma^2$. If $a$ and $b$ are centered with different variances, then $x(t)$ is gaussian centered with variance $\sigma_a^2\sin^2(2πf_0t)+\sigma_b^2\cos^2(2πf_0t)$, depending on $t$.

Comment: Yes, a and b have same variance = 1, but how does that help with the marginal PDF of x(t)?

Comment: This helps because then x(t) is *standard normal* N(0,1).